# How to use Image files in Eclipse (beginner)

Tags: eclipse

I can't work out how to use Image files in Eclipse. I've saved the files to what I think is the relevant folder (the same file where all the classname.java files are stored but the images aren't showing up on in eclipse. I've attached a screenshot by way of explanation[image: the image is a screenshot with the image files I want to access highlighted, but not showing up in eclipse which is in the background]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try dragging the images into the physical tree view in the package explorer. That should work, otherwise, try refreshing the Package Explorer.

Comment: I tried dragging the images in but it gives me an error message saying the source and destination are the same. As for refreshing the package explorer, I've tried closing eclipse down and opening it up but it still hasn't changed :(

Comment: Try deleting the file in the actual folder, refresh the package explorer, then drag it in.

Comment: No problem. Darn this 15 character requirement!

Answer (score 0):

The Package Explorer view can be finicky about what content it shows. The files are there, are visible to Eclipse, but just aren't visible in that view. Try a different nav view, such as Project Explorer. The view that most faithfully shows the actual file contents of a project is Navigator.